# Managing multiple accounts per person in LDAP

Tags: ldap, schema

What is the proper way of organizing data in LDAP such that every person can have multiple accounts.

person<->account should be 1:n.

account<->service should be n:m.

The latter can be realized by having services be represented as groups and assigning accounts to those groups. But I am not certain as to how I should go about separating accounts from persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an account unique identifier to the person entry. This unique identifier can be either the DN of the account entry, or some other unique attribute (i.e. accountID). I personally prefer the later so that you don't have to worry about updating the person entry if you decide to rename or relocate (change the DN) your accounts.

Let's assume you have the following two accounts:

```
dn: accoutnID=accountA,ou=Accounts,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
accoutnID: accountA
desc: Sample Account A

dn: accoutnID=accountB,ou=Accounts,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
accoutnID: accountB
desc: Sample Account B
```

You can establish a one-to-many relationship as follows:

```
dn: uid=bjensen,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: customPerson
uid: bjensen
cn: Barbara Jensen
sn: Jensen
userPassword: XXXXXXX
accountID: accountA
accountID: accountB
```

It depends on your schema, but you might have to customize it to make sure the accountID attribute is allowed for person entries.

You might also want to consider indexing the accountID attribute so that you can efficiently search for all the persons that belong to an account. For example, to find all the users for Account A you'll do:

```
ldapsearch --port 1389 --hostname localhost --bindDN “cn=directory manager” \
--password password123 --baseDN “ou=people,dc=example,dc=com” \
--scope ONE “(&(objectclass=device)(accountID=accountA)”
```